# Adding static content in web config transform

Tags: .net, web-config-transform

I have a Web.Config file for local testing and i have a web.Release.Deploy.config transform that i want to include static content into. 
I am not very familiar with web config transforms. I have added this to the web.release.deploy.config.

```
 <system.webServer xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Should i be adding a rule to this or does the syntax look correct?

or should it look like this since the system.webserver element is not being inserted only the static content?

```
 <staticContent xdt:Transform="Insert">
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer that worked for me was this.

```
 <staticContent xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
```

this worked because the insert is on the static content tag. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but this is how I add additional fileExtensions in my transforms:

```
<staticContent xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
  <remove fileExtension=".css"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <remove fileExtension=".js"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <remove fileExtension=".jpg"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpeg"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"  xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <remove fileExtension=".png"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"  xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".png" mimeType="image/png"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
</staticContent>
```

This works for me because my initial web.config already contained some existing values:

```
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="31.00:00:00" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
</staticContent>
```

Example for @AsierVillanueva since I couldn't format in a comment:

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"  xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />  
<remove fileExtension=".css"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />  
<mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"  xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(fileExtension)" />
```

Comment: ¿But what happens if the web.config already contains an entry for `mimemap` but not the `remove` one?

Comment: You could do a `xdt:Transform="Remove"` to clean out the mismatched mimeMap before using the `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"`  
@AsierVillanueva